# How to create a pricing rule from custom line item referencing a taxonomy term in Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart and I am trying to create a pricing rule for a custom line item that references a taxonomy term that adds an amount to the product's base price.

For the condition, I have chosen "Line item product has term(s)" (I believe that is made available from the commerce rules extra module). My question is what Data selector should be chosen?

I can get it to work if I chose the condition of "entity has field" and then select the field that references the taxonomy.  The problem is, if nothing is selected in the field by the user - the amount is added anyway as this condition just checks for a field

Here is the rule:

`{ "rules_wingstop_plano_tx_options" : {
    "LABEL" : "Wingstop Plano TX Options",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Plano TX", "Wingstop" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_rules_extra",
      "commerce_line_item",
      "commerce_product_reference"
    ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "field" : "field_quantity" } },
      { "AND" : [
          { "commerce_rules_extra_rules_condition_has_terms" : {
              "line_item" : [ "commerce-line-item:order:commerce-line-items:0" ],
              "voc_name" : "wingstop_plano_tx_75074_boneless_wing_options",
              "term_id" : { "value" : { "73" : "73" } },
              "product_display" : "1",
              "term_operator" : "IOO"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_add" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : "300",
          "component_name" : "base_price",
          "round_mode" : "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Thanks in advance to any insight you can give on this.

Scott

Comment: Did you paste the correct rule? I don't see an entity has field condition in it, just a condition from Commerce Rules Extra.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for taking a look at this.  You're correct, I've tried a number of rules and that initial rule I posted didn't have a "entity has field" condition in it.  I've updated it with my latest attempt.